# Docker-compose: error when trying to run mongo image

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to run an image using mongo-compose.

The compose file is this one:

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: mongo:3.4.10
    volumes:
      - ./data/mongodb:/data/db
```

After I run

```
docker-compose -p DropDesk up -d db
```

I get a "done" message, but the container is not running. Checking the container logs, I see this message:

```
exception in initAndListen: 20 Attempted to create a lock file on a read-only directory: /data/db, terminating
```

Besides, if I remove the volume mapping from the compose file, the container works with no problem.

I'm using Centos 7 (Kernel 5), I have disabled selinux, I'm using Docker engine 18.09).

Anyone knows why could this be happening? I have been a couple of hours with no result.

Comment: mongo is very picky with files, have you tried to remove the local `./data/mongodb` folder and use a new one?

for me it's working pretty fine

Answer (score 1):

change your `docker-compose.yml` file to:

```
version: '2'
services:
    db:
        image: mongo:3.4.10
        command: mongod --dbpath /data/db
        volumes:
            - ./data/mongodb:/data/db
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem is related to wrong permissions.

Make sure your `./data` volume endpoint from the `docker-compose.yml` file is located on a user-group-other permission-supported filesystem. Placing the folder on a `NTFS` formated partition will result in the above mentioned error (moving it to `Ext4` will solve this).

Answer (score 0):

Change the permissions to directory `./data/mongodb` so user in docker can write to the directory.